# How to install an extension to TYPO3 using composer

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-extensions

working with TYPO3 and composer to learn TYPO3 basics. 
Got a first problem on trying the composer learning example extensions

```
Could not install distribution 'doc_tut_templating'
Extension Manager is in offline mode. No TER connection available.
```

OK, need to do it by composer. But how to? Just find how to setup TYPO3  with composer or create extension for use with composer. But how to I install an extension with composer?

Regrads n00n

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution. Simply easy, to easy for me....

Search the extension here: 
https://composer.typo3.org/
Search for the extension

Take the name and require it in composer
composer require typo3-ter/[Extension Name]
→ composer require typo3-ter/efempty

Comment: This is outdated. You will now find most extensions on packagist.org. You should require them from packages, not composer.typo3.org (not composer req typo3-ter/extname, but composer req extname). You will find the command for most extensions on https://extensions.typo3.org.

Comment: See note on https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/repository: "This Composer Repository is deprecated.
Please note, the usage of this Composer Repository is deprecated. Instead use the extensions published at Packagist, which is prefered. As fall back for not yet published extensions you can use this repository."

Answer (score 2):

With composer you can only put the sources in their correct positions; an extension still needs to be activated. You can this do in the Extensions model (aka extension manager) or use some automated method like [Helmut's TYPO3 distribution](https://github.com/helhum/TYPO3-Distribution) uses. This distribution uses TYPO3 Surf and TYPO3 Console for a lot of tasks, one of which is activating the extensions which are required using composer.

You can find more information about using TER extensions with composer on the [TYPO3 CMS Composer Repository](https://composer.typo3.org/)

There is a nice article about what should be in a composer.json file for extensions if you need to create such a file: [composer.json specification for TYPO3 extensions](http://insight.helhum.io/post/148886148725/composerjson-specification-for-typo3-extensions)

Comment: I was more searching for the composer command to add an extension. I ´would like to use the extension efempty (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/efempty) to understand the minimum requierement of an extension. But I cannot find it in my typo3 and I do not know what I have to write in composer to insallt it. The Extension does not have a composer.json in it zip...

Comment: I tried to answer that in the second part of the answer: https://composer.typo3.org/ tells you how to use a TER extension in composer. But you already found that out :-)