# Typo3 : Get Extensions option is not showing in Extension module

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

[Where I want that option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLpo2.png)

I want to add a new extension, but I don't have the "Get extension" Option. Please check above screenshot.

Comment: The blue comment in your screenshot says that you cannot use the Extension manager, but you need to use the composer itself. Then you probably need to activate it. This seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791297/how-to-install-an-extension-to-typo3-using-composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the blue box: your instance is running in composer mode, so you have to use composer to install extensions.

Please use `composer require` to add new extensions see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/ExtensionInstallation/Index.html#install-extension-with-composer

Comment: Ok thanks, so I have to disable composer mode. After disable now I can see it.

Comment: No, you can not mix modes. Composer is the recommended way to install TYPO3. So you have to decide using Composer or not. I suggest using Composer. There is no need you can add extensions in the backend, this should be a part of the project setup.

Comment: But I have zip file of the extension. actually I created site package builder from (https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/new/).

Comment: A sitepackage you will place in a path repository for a composer install. I'm currently writting a new guide for the Bootstrap Package and Sitepackagebuilder which also explains how to setup a path repo see https://quick-start.web02.opsone.core.gilbertsoft.net/QuickStart/Index.html. This is primary meant for the usage with DDEV which is also recommended by the way, but you also can use the composer commands with a pure composer omitting the prepended `ddev`