# Typo3: How can i create and show custom content element (example: Email id, Phone number etc.)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have contact persons' list and i want to display his detail(Email,Phone number,Address etc.)
Please give me simple example for the Address field.

I want functionality like the ACF(Advance custom filed plugin which provide in WordPress.
I am using Typo3 9.5.18 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the extension tt_address https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/tt_address/.

Cheers,
Rachel

Comment: I don't want to use any plugin. it will make me complicated. can you explain how to use a custom content element?

Comment: Hello Joy, as far as I understand, you think it's complicated to use a plugin because in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211764/typo3-get-extensions-option-is-not-showing-in-extension-module) you have problems with the composer mode. 

You really should learn how to install plugins (with or without composer) instead of trying to find a workaround that will cost you time and quality. Don't hesitate to also join the slack TYPO3 community, the beginners find a lot of help.

Really, to handle an address list in TYPO3, tt_address IS the easiest way to go.

Cheers,
Rachel

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thanks for your time and suggestion. Actually I am not telling complicated related composer mode issues but I have many custom fields that was not included in the tt_address plugin.

Comment: Ok Joy, in that case, the [Mask extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask) provide a very user friendly way to add custom fields for the contents and the pages, I think it will fit your needs.Cheers,Rachel

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful for me. Have you checked this post? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215137/typo3-how-can-i-assign-page-into-page] 
I need a select box with a page list for assigning pages so I can get all data in that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this:

[How to create complicated content elements](https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-custom-content-elements-on-typo3)

or this:

[How to create simple content elements](https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-simple-custom-content-elements-on-typo3)

or the official documentation:

[Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html)

Regardless what you choose, you need to be aware of the following: In order to create a custom content element you need time to understand how it works patience and do some experiments. Once you understand the process and create 5-10 elements, then all will come automatically to you :)

Best regards